# PresentablePrimaryKeyRelatedFieldSchema extension is not working

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I am very new to drf-spectacular. Actually i have a third party field in my Serializer.

```
class DummySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    dummy_field = PresentablePrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=DummyModel.objects,  
        presentation_serializer=SomeOtherSerializer,
        read_source=None,
    )
```

I want to have drf-spectacular documentation for this field. Like in payload it receives integer value, but in response it will show the whole model field as dictionary.
I got the below extension from drf-specatacular documentation.

```
class PresentablePrimaryKeyRelatedFieldSchema(OpenApiSerializerFieldExtension):
    target_class = PresentablePrimaryKeyRelatedField

    def map_serializer_field(self, auto_schema: AutoSchema, direction: Direction):
        if direction == 'request':
            return build_basic_type(OpenApiTypes.INT)

        meta = auto_schema._get_serializer_field_meta(self.target, direction)
        schema = auto_schema.resolve_serializer(
            self.target.presentation_serializer(
                context=self.target.context, **self.target.presentation_serializer_kwargs,
            ),
            direction,
        ).ref
        return append_meta(schema, meta)
```

I copied/pasted it in my project/schema.py file and then did the import in project/init.py file

project/**init**.py

```
import django
django.setup()

from web.emt_rails import schema
```

Now after running the redoc documentation again, nothing got working. It's like this extension is not registring itself. Am i missing anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The extension needs to be registered with the SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS in your Django settings.

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SERIALIZER_FIELD_EXTENSIONS': [
        'project.schema.PresentablePrimaryKeyRelatedFieldSchema',
    ],
}
```

Comment: Doing that doesn't make any difference. It's like my extension is not even being registered.

Comment: Also do i need to pass the extension in @extend_schema_serializer decorator above my serializer class. If yes, what is the format of passing that extension to decorator?